# How to create new users for sharepoint FBA application using application pages in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, fba

I have successfully configured FBA for my sharepoint application. So i want to create new user from sharepoint site so that they can login & see their profiles. I found webpart solutions from [Here](http://fbaadam.codeplex.com/) but i want to create by myself.
So how can i do this?

My another ouestion is once i create users then my users need to chane their password as well as what if they forget their password. So i need to create those webparts or application pages in visual studio.

So can anyone tell me how can i do all this stuff?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know you can download the source code from CodePlex, right? http://fbaadam.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3afa3d413609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about SQL based FBA. Implementing these solutions is matter of calling appropriate API in `SqlMembershipProvider` class of `System.Web.Security`.

For ex, for change password, see this function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.changepassword.aspx

Similarly, you would many functions in `SqlRoleProvider` class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlroleprovider.aspx